# Calling Apex Methods in React? (Not using LCC - because it seems outdated)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire, react

Hello – in referencing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method

Is there a way to reference apex functions directly in a React component.  I see many examples using LCC.callApex etc but this npm repository doesn’t seem to have been updated in years.  So, can I do something like this in React?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contacts: []
        };
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        @wire(getContactList) contacts;
    }

    ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why LCC is used in those examples is because it is the latest example in current technology. You can't import React code directly into a LWC component, because the LWC compiler would need to know how to compile React; it does not. You can't import LWC into React, as far as I can tell, so React can't support @wire.

Even though both are built on the standard Web Components interface, that's only to say the browser has an API for custom components, so both React and LWC compile into a base implementation the browser understands, but beyond that, they are two entirely different technologies.

The only other popular alternative is to use Visualforce to host the React component; because there's no security (in terms of namespaces or such) in Visualforce. In that case, you can then leverage @RemoteAction methods or use the page's exposed controller methods (via `apex:actionFunction`).

By the way, even if such a construct were possible, you're using @wire incorrectly, I highly doubt this would work. You'd want to call the Apex using:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.contacts = await getContactList();
}
```